# Not able to add Apple developer account in Xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

When I tried to add Apple developer account to Xamarin Studio I got an error.

After entering Apple id and password through Fastlane, I am geting another box to enter login key chain password. After entering login key chain password and on "Always Allow" button click, I am getting following error:

> Error Adding Account - 'Account Name'
>   Failed to parse PList data type:

Xamarin Studio: 6.3
Xcode 9.0

Kindly reply.

Comment: You need to upgrade to Visual Studio (Windows or Mac version) as the Xamarin Studio is deprecated and does not support Xcode 9.0.

Comment: Thanks Sushil, I installed Visual Studio in mac and its working fine.